# Debugging TypeScript Cordova application in VS 2015

Tags: cordova, debugging, typescript, visual-studio-2015

A Cordova projects' typescript source is kept outside of the `www` folder. The generated map file points to source it cannot access. How do I set up a post-build event to copy the typescript source in the `www` folder and update the generated mapping file to enable the debugger to load the correct typescript source file when a breakpoint is hit?

Figured out the first requirement, copying the typescript source files into the `www` folder. Edit the `.jsproj` project file and add the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <TypeScriptSourceFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)scripts\**\*.ts"></TypeScriptSourceFiles>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(TypeScriptSourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(TypeScriptSourceFiles->'$(ProjectDir)www\scripts\ts\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"></Copy>
</Target>
```

Now do I just need to modify the `.js.map` file and update the `sourceRoot` attribute?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for your trouble. We know that we have some issues with source maps and Typescript, depending on the scenario you are debugging. The best way to fix this for now is to add the following setting to your tsconfig.json file:

"inlineSources": true

This will embed your typescript sources in the source map files so that you can debug them in all scenarios.